# Как выровнять подменю в многоуровневом меню с другой стороны, если текст пункта меню длинный?

Tags: jquery, css

**UPD:**

Я применил предложенный способ к выпадающему меню первого уровня, и позиционирование меню второго уровня перестало правильно позиционироваться.
Как правильно прописать, чтобы работало позиционирование для обоих подменю?

```
$("nav ul li").on("mouseover", function(e) {
        $("ul", this).position({
            collision: "flip flipfit",
            my: "left top",
            at: "left bottom",
            of: this,
            within: ".wrapper"
        });
    });

    $("nav ul li li").on("mouseover", function(e) {
        $("ul", this).position({
            collision: "flip flipfit",
            my: "left top",
            at: "right top",
            of: this,
            within: ".wrapper"
        });
    });
```

---

Есть [страница](http://victorpavloff.tmweb.ru/dev/Vershina/inner.html), на которой используется многоуровневое меню на CSS. Сейчас подменю расположено справа от родительского. Но проблема в том, что если текст слишком длинный, то оно не влазит. Как автоматически переместить подменю влево от родительского, если текста больше, чем может поместиться?

**HTML:**

```
<nav>
                    <ul class="header_main_menu">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Главная</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Подбор менеджеров<br>среднего звена</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 2</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 3</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 4</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 5</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="active"><a href="#">Подбор топ менеджеров</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 2</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 3</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 4</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 5</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Тренинги и мастер-классы</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 2</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 3</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 4</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 5</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Оценка персонала</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 2</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 3</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 4</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 5</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">HR брендинг</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 2</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 3</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 4</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 5</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">О компании</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 4</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 5</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Работодателю</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 4</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 5</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Соискателю</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Пункт меню с большим количеством текста 1</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню с большим количеством текста</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню с большим количеством текста</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню с большим количеством текста</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню с большим количеством текста</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню с большим количеством текста</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 2</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 2</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 3</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 4</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 5</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 3</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 2</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 3</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 4</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 5</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 4</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 2</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 3</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 4</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 5</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 5</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 2</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 3</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 4</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 5</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
header nav {
    float: left;
    margin: 16px 0 0 0;
    width: 760px;
    height: 44px;
    position: relative; 
}

#inner_page header nav {
    float: none;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 0 0 13px;
    width: 960px;
}

header nav:before, 
header nav:after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    width: 64px;
    height: 44px;
    -webkit-transform: skew(-29deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-29deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(-29deg);
    -o-transform: skew(-29deg);
    transform: skew(-29deg);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

header nav:before {
    background: #e7bd76;
    top: -14px;
    left: -3px;
}

#inner_page header nav:before {
    top: -40px;
    left: 180px;
}

header nav:after {
    background: #1254ac;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

header nav > ul {
    margin: 0 0 0 12px;
    height: 44px;
    background: #1254ac;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

header nav > ul > li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

header nav > ul > li > a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 18px;
    height: 44px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 44px;
    color: #c7ddfb;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
}

header nav > ul > li:hover > a {
    background: #6398de;
    color: #fff;
}

header nav > ul > li.active > a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

header nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    min-width: 100%;
    background: #6398de;
    position: absolute;
    top: 44px;
    left: 0;
}

header nav ul ul.align_right {
    left: auto;
    right: 0;   
}

header nav li:hover > ul {
    display: block; 
}

header nav ul ul li {
    position: relative; 
}

header nav ul ul a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 18px 9px 18px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #a0c2ee;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
}

header nav ul ul li:last-child a {
    border: none;   
}

header nav ul ul a:hover {
    background: #6fa2e6;
}

header nav ul ul li.active > a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #6fa2e6;
    background: #1254ac;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 0 #6fa2e6;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 0 #6fa2e6;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 0 #6fa2e6;
    font-weight: 700;
}

header nav ul ul ul {
    min-width: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
}

header nav ul ul ul.align_right {
    left: auto;
    right: 100%;    
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите как вы выводите меню.

Comment: Обычые списки http://joxi.ru/Y2Lp6QRSnRV342

Comment: Код лучше добавлять в [вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Показываете подменю средствами jQuery или CSS (:hover)?

Comment: CSS. jQuery вообще не используется.

Comment: Метка jQuery в вопросе для того, что для решения задачи можно использовать jQuery. Но вы же спросили, используется ли jQuery в данный момент. Сейчас не используется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [jQueryUI position](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/). Свойство `collision` равное `flipfit` позволяет размещать элемент в зависимости от наличия свободного места с разных сторон относительно элемента, заданного в свойстве `of`

Примерно так:

```js
$(function($) {
  $('nav ul li li').on('mouseover', function(e) {
    $('ul', this).position({
      collision: 'flip flipfit',
      my: 'left top',
      at: 'right top',
      of: this
    });
  });
});
```

```css
nav > ul > li ul {
  background: #cdc;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px #333;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
nav > ul > li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 10px;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
nav li {
  padding: 3px 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
nav ul ul {
  display: none;
}
nav li li:hover {
  background: #bcb;
}
nav li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul class="header_main_menu">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Главная</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Подбор менеджеров<br>среднего звена</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 3</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 5</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Подбор топ менеджеров</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 3</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 5</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">О компании</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 4</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 5</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Соискателю</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню с большим количеством текста 1</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Пункт меню с большим количеством текста</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Пункт меню с большим количеством текста</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Пункт меню с большим количеством текста</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Пункт меню с большим количеством текста</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Пункт меню с большим количеством текста</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 2</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 3</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Пункт меню 5</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Контакты</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Я так понял он не будет работать при display: none?

Comment: Не очень понял вопрос. Дополнил ответ примером

Comment: То, что нужно, спасибо! Последний вопрос только остался. Как ограничить область, относительно которой пизиционируется меню, конкретным блоком. а не окном?

Comment: Так как там есть блок ".wrapper", у которого overflow:hidden. И поэтому меню не видно, оно за правой границей блока. Перескакивает влево, только если окно браузера уменьшить.

Comment: Разобрался. Свойство within

Comment: Именно :) (Я не постоянно на сайте)

Comment: Я сделал, чтобы еще выпадающее подменю первого уровня выравнивалось также в другую сторону, если не помещается, и подменю второго уровня перестало правильно позиционироваться. http://joxi.ru/L21p9GZS6eyKam

Comment: Селектор в первой части охватывает `li` элементы всех уровней. Поменяйте селектор на `nav > ul > li`

Comment: Я так делал, и все-равно не работает. У меня так в CSS прописано.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48592/discussion-between-tutankhamun-and--).